# Import file loop based on name variable

Tags: excel, vba

I apologise if this is atrociously easy but I have absolutely zero experience with VBA and I'm sort of jumping hurdles as I go along. I've figured out how to import a file from text and convert it as I need using the record macro function. 
I'm now looking to loop this process, based on a file name variable.
The file's I'm looking to import would use the naming convention AB1, AB2, AB3, etc, or something equally as arbitrary, once the file is imported, and converted into the formatting code, it would repeat the process on a new page.

I've tried various coding frameworks from many websites but I can never successfully integrate it into my code already.

```
Sub LoadFromFile()
Dim fileName As String, folder As String

folder = "FILEPATH
fileName = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
    .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder & fileName, 
Destination:=ActiveCell)
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Cells.Select
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Lucida Console"
    .Size = 8
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone

End With
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
  .Orientation = xlLandscape
       .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if the files are all in the same folder u can use a function like this, to get the name off all file in the folder

```
Function listfiles(ByVal sPath As String)

    Dim vaArray     As Variant
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim oFile       As Object
    Dim oFSO        As Object
    Dim oFolder     As Object
    Dim oFiles      As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        vaArray(i) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next

    listfiles = vaArray

End Function
```

and then u can do a "For Each " to get each file and run your code inside it.

good luck